# How to copy values from parent to children in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array with some names as below:

```
[ 
  {
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    children: [
       {
          name: "Max",
          lastName: ""
       },
       {
          name: "Jay",
          lastName: ""
       },
    ]
  },
  {
     ...
  }
]
```

So I have an array with users - some of them have children.
The users on top level have a `lastName` property. I want to copy this value to their children.

Is this possible by doing a remapping?

I am struggling on how to correctly updating the data with values from their "parents".

Comment: I've updated the question to remove TypeScript as it's not really relevant, unless you're having a hard time with types, which you should clarify in the question if it's the case.

Comment: Also, you should provide an [mcve] of what you have right now and what is the current behaviour. Since you've tagged the question with React, it would be helpful to provide a little more context to know if it's relevant as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do nested mapping that creates a new array of parents:

```
arr.map(parent => ({
  ...parent, // (1)
  children: item.children?.map(child => ({
    ...child, // (2)
    lastName: parent.lastName, // (3)
  })
);
```

**(1)** copies all props of each parent but assigns a new array of children that is the result of `map` method on children.

**(2)** copies all props of each child into the new children array

**(3)** assign the `lastName` of the parent

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Max",
        lastName: ""
      },
      {
        name: "Jay",
        lastName: ""
      }
    ]
  }
];

const findNames = () => {
  return data.reduce((res, curr) => {
    const { children = [], lastName = "" } = curr;
    const childrenWithName = children.map((v) => ({
      ...v,
      lastName: lastName
    }));
    return [...res, { ...curr, children: childrenWithName }];
  }, []);
};

const res = findNames(data);
console.log(res);
```

Or you can view solution in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-torvalds-dzgpm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with types

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Typescript problem, as much as it is a Javascript problem. Unless you are asking how to model the type of that.

But the code should be pretty simple. Loop over elements in the array, if the children property is not undefined, loop over it, and set the last name to the parent last name. Pseudo code:

```
For each parent
     If children != undefined
           For each child
               child.LastName = parent.LastName
```

Comment: In addition to not providing a full example, the pseudo code provided suggests mutating the current data, which is an anti-pattern in React (a tag on the question).

Comment: Nowhere in his question did he state that this was component state, so I didn't worry about it. This could be anywhere in his code base. A tag does not tell me where he is wanting to use the code. In addition, I left some details up to the implementer to help him learn. The purpose of this site is to help people learn, not spoon feed them.